# Is the term 'User Experience Designer' grammatically correct?

Tags: word-usage

Today, the buzzword in technology is 'User Experience Design (UX Design)' I'm aware of the meaning but then is it grammatically correct?

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience_design) mentions it here:

> User experience design (UXD or UED) is ***the process*** of enhancing customer satisfaction and loyalty by improving the usability, ease of use, and pleasure provided in the interaction between the customer and the product.

The question came to my mind as I was writing a webpage on *User Experience Designer (UX Designer)* which is the most searched keywords/phrase on the search engines these days. I'm not utterly convinced with the term 'User Experience Designer' as compared to *[User Interface (UI) Designer](http://careers.mozilla.org/en-US/position/oPWnYfwQ)* which is perfect.

How can one design *user experience!*

Comment: "How can one design user experience!" - there's [a whole Stack Exchange site about just that...](http://ux.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Yes, the designing of a user experience can become: User Experience Design. A user experience and a user interface are not the same thing at all.

Answer (score 1):

I really wouldn't worry about it too much.

There was a time when a design was a physical drawing on a physical piece of paper, and only physical things could be designed.

However, long before we knew what a *user interface* was, people started designing abstract things as well: lifestyle design, public image design, happiness design, you name it, there have been people designing it.

Now *experience* can certainly be designed, especially if we define *experience* as "the whole of all things perceived by the user's senses as he uses our application" - It is hardly any vaguer than *user interface*.

Make sure you use the correct abbreviations, though, *User Experience Designer* can be *UX Designer* or *UE Designer*, but not *UI designer* ;)

Comment: Ah, thanks... I just messed it. Corrected UI Designer to UX.

Comment: But then... Bentley, in its cars, does not *design driver's experience* but it does *design for* driver's experience'. That way, one should not *design UX* but *design for (better) UX.*